# When using eval() in Python 3.x to evaluate input, how not to get an error with a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

I am learning Python 3.x. I want to write a function which evaluates inputted values and prints the result. If the string originally is inputted, the function should just print the string without evaluation.

```
def eval_input():
    line=input("Something:")
    print(eval(line))

eval_input()
```

It works fine with integers and mathematical operations.
But when a string gets inputted, like "`fasdfasd`", it gets an error: "`name 'fasdfasd' is not defined`".
I understand why this error happens. Because "`fasdfasd`" is seen as a variable.
But I don't understand how to check whether a string was originally inputted?

How do I filler strings from the input before evaluating it?

Comment: Why use eval :(

Comment: As others have said, `eval()` is not a good idea here. Instead, parse the data manually.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First: It's rarely a good idea to rely on  `eval()`.

You could simply catch the `NameError` (and `SyntaxError` as well) and assume the input was a string:

```
try:
    print(eval(line))
except (NameError, SyntaxError):
    print(line)
```

There may be other exceptions raised here, but next to avoid using `eval()` I also want to caution against using a blanket `except:` or `except Exception:` handler, those are generally also not good ideas.

A better technique would be to use [`ast.literal_eval`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) instead:

```
try:
    print(ast.literal_eval(line))
except ValueError:
    print(line)
```

`literal_eval` only accept python literal values (so `'string'` or `123` or `('some', 'more', [1, 2, 4.5], 'complex structure')`) and will throw a `ValueError` if it cannot parse that input.

It does *not* suffer from the security problems that `eval()` suffers from, nor do you need to catch as many exceptions, only `ValueError` needs to be handled.

Comment: Surely this will still explode for `something like this` as a `Syntax Error` ?

Comment: @JakobBowyer: there are probably more, but I am not going to advocate using a blanket except if I can avoid it. :-)

Comment: Agreed but at least catching exceptions in respect to eval will be pretty broad

Comment: @JakobBowyer: two bad ideas together, one precipitating the other. *humbug*.

Comment: Thank you, Martijin Pieters! I was thinking there should be something like catching an error, but I did not know about NameError, try and except. It perfectly solves my problem. And I got the message that I shouldn't use eval(). I will use it only for studying purpose. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

If you are taking user input, presumable you know what you are asking for and what type it should be. You need to write a verifier. You can do this textually with regular expressions, or more basically with "casts", or conversion functions.

For example, if you are looking for an integer number, use `int` to convert it, and check for errors.

```
>>> int("22")
22
>>> int("asdf")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'asdf'
>>>
```

Tell the user to enter a number. The `int` function will raise ValueError if it can't parse it, and only that , so you can easily tell that you got something other than a number.

```
>>> try: 
...     int("asdf")
... except ValueError:
...     print("Enter a number please")
...
```

You can do the same with `float`. What you get from `input` is always a `str`, so if that's what you want just use that.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, simply as an answer I'm going to put this

```
try:
    print(eval(line))
except Exception as e:
    print "Something went wrong, namely: %s" % e
```

But you really don't want to use eval, its evil, nasty, leads to bugs and security risks, and is hard to develop, debug and use properly